# Required FileUpload[] parameter 'body' is not present in Spring boot file upload with json

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to upload file with json as a request Parameter. But it says FileUpload body is not present.

Here is my Controller.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public Flux<FileUpload> upload(@RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> filePartFlux,
                                    @RequestParam("body") FileUpload[] fileUploads) {
        return fileUploadService.saveFile(filePartFlux, fileUploads);
    }
```

Here is my service.

```
@Override
public Flux<FileUpload> saveFile(Flux<FilePart> filePartFlux, FileUpload[] fileUpload) {
    List<FileUpload> list = Arrays.asList(fileUpload);
    Flux<FileUpload> file = Flux.fromIterable(list);

    upload(filePartFlux);

    fileUploadRepository.saveAll(file);

    return null;
}
```

And in Postman I tried this but error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestParam("body")
```

In WebFlux, @RequestParam indicator only binds query parameters.
ref docs :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-requestparam

If you want to get formData, you should use `ServerWebExchange`